# Why does my PZEM-004T module not measure?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a task at work to measure power consumption of devices with Arduino and a PZEM-004T module. I connected the Arduino Mega R3 2560 to the PZEM (PINs 18 and 19 for TX and RX). The Arduino Mega is connected to a computer through USB (A to B). This is the code:

```
#include <PZEM004Tv30.h>

PZEM004Tv30 pzem(18, 19); // Software Serial pin 18 (RX) & 19 (TX)

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   float voltage = pzem.voltage();
   if(voltage != NAN){
       Serial.print("Voltage: ");
       Serial.print(voltage);
       Serial.println("V");
   } else {
       Serial.println("Error reading voltage");
   }

   float current = pzem.current();
   if(current != NAN){
       Serial.print("Current: ");    
       Serial.print(current);
       Serial.println("A");
   } else {
       Serial.println("Error reading current");
   }

   float power = pzem.power();
   if(current != NAN){
       Serial.print("Power: ");
       Serial.print(power);
       Serial.println("W");
   } else {
       Serial.println("Error reading power");
   }

   float energy = pzem.energy();
   if(current != NAN){
       Serial.print("Energy: ");
       Serial.print(energy,3);
       Serial.println("kWh");
   } else {
       Serial.println("Error reading energy");
   }

   float frequency = pzem.frequency();
   if(current != NAN){
       Serial.print("Frequency: ");
       Serial.print(frequency, 1);
       Serial.println("Hz");
   } else {
       Serial.println("Error reading frequency");
   }

   float pf = pzem.pf();
   if(current != NAN){
       Serial.print("PF: ");
       Serial.println(pf);
   } else {
       Serial.println("Error reading power factor");
   }

   Serial.println();
   delay(2000);
}
```

When I upload the code, the serial monitor prints:

```
Voltage: nanV
Current: nanA
Power: nanW
Energy: nankWh
Frequency: nanHz
PF: nan
```

My PZEM has L and N connected to voltage and it doesn't measure it. Why?

Comment: Have you checked whether the PZEM has the correct address on the bus? According to the [repo](https://github.com/mandulaj/PZEM-004T-v30/blob/master/PZEM004Tv30.h), the constructor you used receives an optional parameter `addr` which defaults to `0xF8`.
Also, you might want to use `isnan(...)` instead of `== NAN` to check for `NaN`.

Comment: not all Mega pins support SoftwareSerial. but Mega has 4 hardware serials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Pins 10 and 11 support SoftwareSerial on Arduino Mega R3 2560 so I had to move them from pins 18TX and 19RX.

Comment: Why are you using software serial? Mega has 4 hardware serial ports.